# facebook profile pic not working in div tag in firefox

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
  <div>
      <img src='http://graph.facebook.com/<?php $user->id ?>/picture'/>;
</div>
```

this is the code that i m using to get a facebook profile pic in div ,this div tag is running in java script ,when i run this code in chrome it works well,but in firefox it get blink and then image comes,pls help anybody thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to show us more code, also you need to `echo` the user id:

```
<img src='http://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user->id ?>/picture' alt='' />
```